# How to route DooPHP URIs that include querystring?

Tags: doophp

I need to be able route requests that pass information in the querystring. For example, let's say my application calls /api/company/delete?id=17. How can I route that in DooPHP? I already have a catchall route defined, which is grabbing this request, but I need to be able to process these without a catchall route.

```
# this doesn't work
$route['get']['/api/company/delete?id=:id'] = array('AdminController', 'deletecompany');

# at the bottom of my routes I have this catchall route, which works but it catches --everything--
$route['*']['catchall']['/:id'] = array('HomeController', 'getregions');
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

routes
$route['get']['/api/company/delete/:id'] = array('AdminController', 'deletecompany');

controller
$this->params['id']

or

routes
$route['post']['/api/company/delete'] = array('AdminController', 'deletecompany');

controller
$_POST['id']